# How to compare 2 strings in groovy?

Tags: groovy

There are 2 strings in groovy files :1) 01xx01xx01 and 2) 0101010111 and I want to compare only non-x elements. eg only compare 010101 with 010111 (ignore "x"). The following scripts were created by me (written in groovy). It works but needs many lines of code. Are there any other ways to do it?

```
a="01xx01xx01"
b="0101010111"
def compareStrings(String a,String b){
    i=0
    while (i<a.length){
        if (a[i] =="X" || b[i]=="X"){
            i+=1}
        else if (a[i]!=b[i]){
            return "Not Similar"}
        else{
            i+=1}
    return "Similar"
    }
}
def result = compareStrings(str1,str2)  
println(result)
```

Comment: your provided example code can't be run. multiple variables are not defined, also intendation is wrong. It looks like you only print "match" multiple times if the compared numbers are equal without additional information which doesn't make a lot of sense? Could you please edit your desired output with all information we need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> There are 2 strings in groovy files :1) 01xx01xx01 and 2) 0101010111 and I want to compare only non-x elements. eg only compare 010101 and 010111.

working Groovy code below

```
println "str match"

def str1 = '01xx01xx01'
def str2 = '0101010111'
def str3 = '01xx01xx01'

def sameStringsIgnoreX(str1,str2) {
    def temp1 = str1.replaceAll('x','')
    def temp2 = str2.replaceAll('x','')
    temp1 == temp2

}

def sameStrings = sameStringsIgnoreX(str1,str2)
println(sameStrings)

sameStrings = sameStringsIgnoreX(str1,str3)
println(sameStrings)
```

output

```
str match
false
true
```

Comment: Not sure this works 100%...  Consider `'0101010101'` and `'01xx01xx01'`...  They should be the same, no?

Comment: This is not right. Can't simply replace "x" with "0" and compare

Answer (score 1):

**Python**

**See my approach. Hope you like it.**

**Code:-**

```
def compare_strings(string1,string2):
    # Edge case:- When both strings have different length
    if len(string1)!=len(string2):
        return "Not similar"
    length=len(string1)
    i=0
    while i<length:  #You can apply for loop also the edge case of different length is checked above. so there will be no error of index out of range
        if a[i]=="x" or b[i]=="x":
            i+=1
        elif a[i]!=b[i]:
            return "Not Similar"
        else:
            i+=1
    return "Similar"
# Comparisons of two strings Test Case 1 Same Length Not similar
a="01xx01xx01" 
b="0101010111"    
print(compare_strings(a,b))
# Comparisons of two strings Test Case 2 Same Length similar
a="01xx01xx01" 
b="0101010001"
print(compare_strings(a,b))
# Comparisons of two strings Test Case 3 Different Length
a="01xx01xx01" 
b="0101010"
print(compare_strings(a,b))
```

**Output:-**

```
Not Similar
Similar
Not similar
```

Answer (score 1):

Different Groovy technique

```
boolean sameStringsIgnoreX(String a, String b) {
    [a, b]*.toList().transpose().findAll { 'x' !in it }.every { it[0] == it[1] }
}

def str1 = '01xx01xx01'
def str2 = '0101010111'
def str3 = '01xx01xx01'


def sameStrings = sameStringsIgnoreX(str1,str2)
println(sameStrings)

sameStrings = sameStringsIgnoreX(str1,str3)
println(sameStrings)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a="01xx01xx01"
b="0101010111"
def compareStrings(String a,String b){
    i=0
    while (i<a.length){
        if (a[i] =="X" || b[i]=="X"){
            i+=1}
        else if (a[i]!=b[i]){
            return "Not Similar"}
        else{
            i+=1}
    return "Similar"
    }
}
def result = compareStrings(str1,str2)  
println(result)
```